# Why async.forEach callback is never getting called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async.js

In Below code, I am using `forEach` and in it, I am iterating over an array, and inside forEach I am calling another function while passing the parameter as `callback`, Now the thing is even I am calling this callback from the function, the `forEach` callback is never getting called

```
async.forEach(Array_Ids, function (item, callback){
    sendPushNotif(item.mess, item.Ids, callback);
}, function(err) {
    // EXECUTION NEVER COMING HERE
    if(err) {
         res.json({status_code : 200, message : "Correctly Hit the URL!"});
         return next();
    } else {
         res.json({status_code : 200, message : "Correctly Hit the URL!"});
         return next();
    }
});

function sendPushNotif(mess, Ids, callback) {
sender.send(mess, { registrationTokens: Ids }, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        callback(null);
    }
    else {
        console.log(null);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: I think that `sendPushNotif` doesn't call `callback` on some reason. Try to wrap callback as same way `sendPushNotif((err, res) => {console.log('Done', item); callback(err, res);});`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Can you please have a relook again, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only invoke `callback()` conditionally here:

```
function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    callback(null);
  }
  else {
    console.log(null);
  }
}
```

If you want to suppress errors, you can replace the `if`/`else` with

```
callback(null);
```

If you want to propagate errors, you can replace the whole `function` expression with

```
callback
```

Comment: Actually, I wrote `conditions` because I want to do something there but as my code isn't running successfully that's why they are left right now.

Comment: Either way, the first sentence in my answer explains why your code doesn't work. I provided solutions for your given example, and you can infer how to fix the code you haven't shared.

Comment: The error was I was using `console.log("null")` not `callback(null)` :(, I am really having a Bad day :(